# How do I properly create an array of 2d int arrays in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, command-line-arguments, definition

I will have multiple 2d int arrays..

```
int[5][5] A;
int[5][5] B;
int[5][5] C;
```

but how many I need is dependent on a parameter decided on runtime. How would I create a dynamic amount of 2D arrays and manage them?

Comment: Have a look at this link: http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C you may use Variable Length Arrays (VLA). So you can declare one three dimensional array the left dimension of which will specify the number of two dimensional arrays.

For example

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
   // some check that the command line parameter was specified
   int a[atoi( argv[1] )][5][5];
}
```

Comment: So essentially a[0][5][5] and a[1][5][5]are A[5][5] and B[5][5] ?

Comment: Fantastic, I appreciate it. Is this a common way of handling this in C?

Comment: @Jordan H I do not know whether it is a common way or not. The idea came to me just now. Your compiler must support C99.

Comment: @JordanH: not knowing how many arrays you'll need until runtime is a fairly unusual requirement; Vlad's suggestion is about as good as you'll get.  The alternative is using dynamic memory allocation with `malloc()` et al; that too gets hairy (and as long as the total size of the arrays is small enough to fit on your stack), VLAs are notationally very convenient.

Comment: You should check if the command-line parameter was specified; otherwise, the program will give a segmentation fault.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
int* myArr = malloc(x_dim*y_dim*sizeof(int)); // malloc guarantees contiguous memory allocation
```